# print value in to a div with jquery after press submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make a form with a select option. After the user presses submit, I want to print the value into a `div`. How can I do that with jQuery?

[Here's a demo on Codepen](https://codepen.io/index1337/pen/bWzEVy).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".p" ).append( $( "h6" ) );
})
```

Comment: Do you want that the `submit` button actually will submit the form to a server or just do a client manipulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use a submit button unless you intend to send that data to a server. In fact you don't need a button at all if you register the `<select>` on the `change` event. Instead of a div use `<output>` that way you can just use the `.val()` method without having to switch over to `.html()` or `.text()`

### Demo

```js
$('#sel').on('change', function() {
  $('#out').val($(this).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id='sel'>
  <option value="">----</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select><br/>
<output id='out'></output>
```

Comment: `After the user presses submit` Where is the submit button?

Answer (score 0):

To get value use:

```
$('#dropDownId').val();
```

To get the currently selected text use:

```
$('#dropDownId :selected').text();
```